# Подсчет кол-ва дней и форматирование результата между двумя датами

Tags: php, дата, datetime

Я работаю над реализацией графика продаж. У меня есть ось Х. ВВерху на странице есть фильтр, который позволяет ввести диапазон дат, то есть сначала вводим дату от, затем дату до.

Мне необходимо определить, как выводить даты на оси Х.

Я предполагаю делать это так:

К примеру, если человек ввел 2 даты в пределе одного месяца, или между месяцами, но не более чем скажем 31 день, то мне необходимо получить массив, где будут элементы по дням.

То есть ось Х будет вида: 01.10.2017, 02.10.2017,...31.10.2017.

Но если же пользователь ввел 2 даты в диапазоне больше чем 31, то необходимо уже вывести массив из 2 дат. Первый элемент это первый месяц, второй это второй.

В этом случае на оси Х должно быть 10.2017, 12.2017

Если человек ввел диапазон более чем 12 мес, то уже необходимо выводить годами.

В этом случае на оси Х должно быть 2016, 2017

Подсчет количества дней между двумя датами я делаю так:

```
    $datetime1 = date_create("01.05.2017");
    $datetime2 = date_create("31.05.2017");
    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
    $days = $interval->format('%a');

    if($days <= 31)
      {
        $period = new DatePeriod(
         new DateTime($dateFrom),
         new DateInterval('P1D'),
         (new DateTime($dateTo))->modify('+1 days')
      );

      //Абсцисса Х
      $daysArray;
      foreach( $period as $date) {
          $daysArray .= "'".$date->format('Y-m-d')."',";
      }
      }

if($days > 31 && $days < 365)
{
 //Тут уже необходимо выводить не дни а месяца в формате m.Y

$period = new DatePeriod(
         new DateTime($dateFrom),
         new DateInterval('P1D'),
         (new DateTime($dateTo))->modify('+1 month')
      );

      //Абсцисса Х
      $daysArray;
      foreach( $period as $date) {
          $daysArray .= "'".$date->format('Y-m-d')."',";
      }
    }
```

После echo $daysArray я получаю то что мне нужно. Но мой код работает только в приделах 31 дня, если я добавлю условие >31 дня то мне уже необходимо вывести только даты по месяцам. **Я по аналогии с <31 вывожу но в modify ставлю +1 month** но в результате я получаю по дням, а не по месяцам.

Вопрос как это реализовать?

Comment: ну используй тот же `DatePeriod` только с интервалом по месяцам и годам соответственно

Comment: а вот и не работает так. я пробовал менять на +1 month в ->modify но оно всеравно выводит по дням..

Comment: а причём тут +1 month в ->modify? Интервал задается в DateInterval, что логично по названию

Comment: При том что насколько я понимаю в modify указывается на какие равные куски разбивается дата. Возможно тогда отредактируете мой код что бы получилось то что необходимо?

Comment: Интервал задается в **DateInterval**, что логично по названию

Comment: Блин, точно! спасибо! Работает, P1D

Comment: А может подскажете еще по поводу логики, верно ли так размышлять в том контексте задания которое у меня есть. Я про определение интервала в год или месяц или дни в зависимости от кол-ва дней в диапазоне между датами?